# Colocar limite, css animations

Tags: html, css, html5

Me deparei com este problema que esta afetando minha estrutura CSS.

tenho tal animação em meu site http://jsfiddle.net/9bdqe2nq/

Porém preciso que ela se mantenha dentro da barra preta, ou seja aquele excedente que fica fora da barra nao deve aparecer... Eu estava usando o z-index para sobre por o resto do meu site em cima daquilo, porém obtive problemas [..]

Qual solução devo aplicar?

Comment: [Seria isso](http://jsfiddle.net/9bdqe2nq/3/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow), dessa maneira o que sai fora da div não é mostrado, fica escondido.

```
.menu {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bdqe2nq/1/

Comment: Vejamos, funciona certo, porem eu preciso exibir outras divs dentro do .menu que vao alem do height do menu, como aqui http://jsfiddle.net/9bdqe2nq/2/ @Sergio

Comment: @user3163662, assim o problema fica diferente. Posso sugerir mudanças no HTML?

Comment: fique avontade, aguardo reply!

Comment: EDIT: Solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar

```
overflow: hidden;
```

no classe .menu { }